# How to display a user's name on a welcome message after login using Firebase in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read user information as soon as they log in, and use it on the following HTML page where the user can view their designated training. Right now, I'm just trying to read the name to later use it on the training portal in a welcome message, specifically in an "h1Welcome to the training portal, !/h1."My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getDatabase, onValue, ref } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-database.js";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {

    //firebaseconfig...
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase();
const analytics = getAnalytics();
const auth = getAuth();

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        const userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
        const athleteRef = ref(database, `Athletes/${userID}/firstname`);
        // Si hay un usuario autenticado, lee su nombre de la base de datos y actualiza la página
        onValue(athleteRef, (snapshot) => {
            const nombre = snapshot.val();
            document.getElementById('nombre-atleta').textContent = nombre;
        });
    } else {
        console.log("error")
        window.location.href = "loginTrainMate.html";
    }
});
```

However, I keep getting an error that says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments." on line 2. How can I fix this issue and properly read the user's name to use on the training portal page? Thank you!